# How to add a border all labels to an array of labels in an outlet collection in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, uilabel, iboutletcollection

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        labels[0].layer.borderWidth = 1
        labels[0].layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `loop` through the `labels` and set the `border` as below,

```
labels.forEach { (label) in
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
}
```